# set date format into react code using configuration

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flatpickr

I have this code which is used to generate date selection drop down:

```
   <Flatpickr
      id="fromDate"
      style={dateFilterComponentsStyle}
      value={dateFrom.getTime() === 0 ? '' : dateFrom}
      onChange={([date]) => {
        setDateFrom(date);
      }}
    />
```

I found here how to configure custom date and settings:

https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/

But it's not clear how I can do this into the react code. Can you guide me how I can apply these settings?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-flatpickr, then you can pass options into the component

```
<Flatpickr options={{ dateFormat: "d.m.Y" }} />
```

This should work for all flatpickr options in the docs :)